# What is the possibility of making asp.net web application update itself?

Tags: c#, asp.net, auto-update

I have a web application that i would like it to check for updates, download and install them.

i know there are already some updater frameworks that works for windows applications, but is it possible for web applications ?

The first thing came to my mind when thinking of this is:

File permissions *(i might not be able to replace all my application files due to file permissions)*

Also touching the web.config or the bin folder will cause the application to restart.

I also thought about executing an exe from my web application that does the job, but i dont know if it could get shutdown because of a restart to the web application.

I would appreciate any ideas or solution to that case.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for your question yet? Although they depend on different technologies wordpress, etc. can do what you're asking for... Additionally, about the possible restart problem, an updater web app might be employed and triggered by the application that needs an update... (just a quick thought...)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy)

It is meant to ease such tasks. Where you want to deploy a publish to a production server.

Rather than having your server check for updates and update itself, it would be simpler to just push updates to it when you have them.

> Web Deploy allows you to efficiently synchronize sites, applications
>   or servers across your IIS 7.0 server farm by detecting differences
>   between the source and destination content and transferring only those
>   changes which need synchronization. The tool simplifies the
>   synchronization process by automatically determining the
>   configuration, content and certificates to be synchronized for a
>   specific site. In addition to the default behavior, you still have the
>   option to specify additional providers for the synchronization,
>   including databases, COM objects, GAC assemblies and registry
>   settings.

- Administrative privileges are not required in order to deploy Web
  applications.
- Server administrators have granular control over the operations that can be performed and can delegate tasks to non-administrators.

This needs you to be running IIS7 though.

Comment: I dont know if WebDeploy is the best solution, how can i auto-update my application, weather its a check for updates every specific time or even when the user triggers it?

Comment: Whenever you want to release a new version of your application, you can just deploy it. Why should a user check? Are these servers not in your control?

Comment: The servers is under my control, however there alot of this application installed on the server, and i want to update them all, and how about executing sql scripts to update the database too ?

Comment: No matter what you are deploying this can help. It can sync databases, COM objects, GAC assemblies and registry settings.

Comment: how about deploying to a multi applications, is this possible using webdeploy ? i cant seem to find it. and i appreciate your concern.

Comment: I do not understand the multi application part properly. You can deploy one application to multiple servers. If you have many different applications that you want to deploy together, you could probably host them in virtual directories and deploy that.

Comment: its an application like wordpress that has many copies, i want to be able to update them all from a specific version that i upload, each copy has its own domain so i dnt know about virtual directories